# SharePoint Search Result Source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

I want to get pages library data by language (English and German). I have created two result source in SharePoint search. In Query transform I have given below condition. But it is not filtering data as per language wise. I only want to get English variance site data in EnglishResultSource1 and German variance site data in GermanResultSource2.

EnglishResultSource1

```
{searchTerms} contentclass=STS_ListItem_850 -Path=siteurl/en-us/
```

GermanResultSource2

```
{searchTerms} contentclass=STS_ListItem_850 -Path=siteurl/de-de/
```

But in result source it is not filtering data by path wise.

How can I filter by language/locate wise?

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have "-Path" the minus sign means you're negating the current property. So the first line reads, show items where the path does NOT equal 'siteurl/en-us'. It should probably be:

```
EnglishResultSource1 {searchTerms} contentclass=STS_ListItem_850 Path:siteurl/en-us/

GermanResultSource2 {searchTerms} contentclass=STS_ListItem_850 Path:siteurl/de-de/
```

You can view the reference for the NOT operator here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911(v=office.15).aspx#kql_operators